# How to pass a variable as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, html-table, row, edit

I have this function that turns cells with class editable (`td.editable`) to input fields. Now, you have to pass the row to the function. For example: `editRow(myRow)`.

So using `this.parentNode.id`, I get the id of the row. But when I pass the value as a parameter to the `editRow` function, it does nothing.

I think the function thinks that `rowId` is the actual name of the row, instead of using the contents of the `rowId` variable as the name of the row.

```
function editRow(row) {
 $('td.editable',row).each(function() {
  $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" size="10" />');
 });
}    

/* click on cell with .editable class */
 $(".editable").click(function() {
   rowId = this.parentNode.id;
   editRow(rowId);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`editRow` doesn't take a row id, it takes an entire row (the DOM Element itself). You're simply passing the wrong data. Try:

```
$('.editable').click(function(){
    editRow(this.parentNode);
});
```

Comment: Yep. [`jQuery( selector, [context] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) - "**context** - A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context"

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions. It works great now! I just got 2 more issues now.


1) If I click on the row, it works as expected. But if I click in another row, it goes into edit mode but the row I clicked first also remains in edit mode, so now I got two or even more rows in edit more. I tried `return false` but it doesn't help.

2) If I click the same row twice or more times, it keeps on adding input fields.

Can anybody help me with these please?

Answer (score 0):

Given your function here:

```
/* click on cell with .editable class */
$(".editable").click(function() {
rowId = this.parentNode.id;
editRow(rowId);
});
```

You are passing the id to your editRow function. So inside editRow, you can just do this:

```
function editRow(row) {
    $('#' + row +' td.editable').each(function() {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" size="10" />');
    });
}
```

'#' is the jquery id selector